# Sails.js: Sending 500 ("Server Error") and User not defined at eval

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to create a view show in Sails. This is my code:

api / models / User.js:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
  }
};
```

api / controllers / UserController

Controller

```
module.exports = {
    new:function (req, res) {
        console.log('entre al formulario');
        res.view();
    },
    create:function(req, res){
        var userObj={
            name : req.param('name'),
            lastname : req.param('lastname'),
            username : req.param('username')
        }
        User.create(userObj, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                console.log("Se encontro un error");
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
            res.redirect('/user');
            console.log("correcto");
        });
    },
    show: function(req, res, next){
        User.findOne(req.param('id'), function userFounded(err, user){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
                return next(err);
            res.view({
                user: user
            });
        });
    }
};
```

And this is my view:

[Show.ejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KRrB.png)

When I go to localhost:1337/user/show/ this error comes out:

[Error showing in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBhwR.png)

However, I can insert, but I can't view the elements in the view show.ejs. Does someone know how to solve this?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your page with `sails generate page *name*` then you should have a *name*.page.js . There you have an `data() {}` section. In this section you have to define your user like `user: {}`

Comment: I created the page just with new file and saved with extension .ejs but when I go to the localhost:1337/user/show/(id_user). I get a message 404. The page you were trying to reach doesn't exist. But the users are created.

Comment: There could be a couple of things going on. I think you want `localhost:1337/user/find/(id)`, with 'find' instead of 'show'. Another problem that you might be having is that in config/blueprints.js, you'll want to set shortcuts to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem has been that I have not put the routes in the  config/routes.js.